# Как изменить Primary Dark для каждого layout'a?

Tags: android, style, themes

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подстроить цвет colorPrimaryDark для каждого слоя? Пробовал через `style="@style/Orange"` и `android:theme="@style/Orange"` , но так не работает.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/textLight</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/action_bar</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Orange" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorTopBarMenuDark</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Цвета схемы описываются без префикса `android:`

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorTopBarMenuDark</item>
```

И на всякий случай напомню, что тема прописывается в манифесте:

```
<application
    ....
    android:theme="@style/Orange">
```